# Remove default ID attribute from HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default, MVC's input html helpers generate "id" and "name" with the same value. In my case i do not need the id, and when i do, I always enter a custom value. Auto generating unnecessary id's increases the document size, and makes me nerves, because i might be using the same id in my CSS or JavaScript code.

Can i alter the default behavior of the html helpers, so the id is not generated unless manually defined.

I know that i can tell the helpers not to generate an id by passing `new { id = "" }`, but this approach is not very convenient for large, data-entry-type applications.

Is there an easy way to alter this behavior, or do i need to write custom html helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use,

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text).RemoveNameIdAttribute()

public static MvcHtmlString RemoveNameIdAttribute(this MvcHtmlString helper)
{
            if (helper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var element = helper.ToString();
        var regex = new Regex("(id|name)[^'\"]*['\"][^'\"]*['\"]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(regex.Replace(element, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can override the default behavior of the HTML Helpers... but can give some bits of advice.

I'm not worried about extra "id" normally, as proper CSS structure and convention can help to prevent that. Where there can be conflict, send in a `new { id = "foo", name = "foo" }`.

I seriously doubt that the "id = myfield" characters are going to add up to much. If you're interested in compression, you could take a look at Combres: (http://combres.codeplex.com/).

Outside of this, the solution may be to create your own HTML helpers, which can override the basic ones, passing in your `new { id = "" }` (Haven't tested that.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: As far as i know Combres minimizes static files (CSS & HTML), which i am already achieving with a customized version of AJAx min. At this point i just need to get rid of the unused html attributes.