# How to generate HTML using ASP.NET MVC helper without the id property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need a certain tag to be repeated many times inside a page. I do prevent the possible server requests with the help of JavaScript. The problem is that the helper generated the html which already contains and **id** with the name of the property on the model.

I can of course delete the id after receiving the HTML.

Or have an empty id by writing something like:

```
Html.Dropdown(something , new {id=""})
```

But all these solutions seem some workarounds rather than the semantically correct ones

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use the standard HTML select?

Comment: @Sitnam, suppose my view has 3 or 4 drop-downs and drawing tham with the standard HTML is possible but too verbose. Also if we have such feature, we must try to use it, right?

Comment: It is Verbose, but just because a HTML Extension exists doesn't really mean that we "Have" to use them under all circumstances. However what I really want to know is what you are doing, some more code, would really help.

Comment: I have four select in a partial. After I have returned it, I save the html and clone it a lot. Actually this partial is a query item which can be combined with and/or. So I do not want to have the tags with the same id on the form

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6977600/1036689